# Unity3d - Define event in another script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Let's say I would like to add functionality to the `OnSelect()` Event of a dropdown element.

Normally I would just add a new script to the specific dropdown gameObject:

[image: Dropdown script]

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class LanguageDropdown : MonoBehaviour, ISelectHandler// required interface when using the OnSelect method.
{
    //Do this when the selectable UI object is selected.
    public void OnSelect(BaseEventData eventData)
    {
        Debug.Log(this.gameObject.name + " was selected");
    }
}
```

*Hint*: The script simply outputs a message if the Dropdown is getting selected.

---

**Question**: Is it possible to define the functionality inside another script?
E.g. I have a script attached to the master parent "Menue" where I am referencing this specific dropdown gameobject.

How can I define the `OnSelect` inside another script?

**PS:** Is this the correct place to ask this question, or should I ask it on gamedevelopement instead?

Comment: @Programmer, I think your comment landed in the wrong section ;)

Comment: lol that's right. That was made for [Ed Marty](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47040648/3785314)'s answer that uses `UnityEvent` and I was in a hurry. I think he saw that.

Comment: Worrying about speed in a user interaction event is *definitely* premature optimization. If performance is not an issue, making the code simple and readable trumps making it efficient *(as long as it's not a bad design)*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use event and delegate. You can find a simplified tutorial for that [here](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/events) if this is new to you.

It should be something like this:

```
public delegate void SelectAction(GameObject target);
public static event SelectAction OnSelectedEvent;
```

Add that to your `LanguageDropdown` script and you should get this:

```
public class LanguageDropdown : MonoBehaviour, ISelectHandler// required interface when using the OnSelect method.
{
    public delegate void SelectAction(GameObject target);
    public static event SelectAction OnSelectedEvent;

    //Do this when the selectable UI object is selected.
    public void OnSelect(BaseEventData eventData)
    {
        Debug.Log(this.gameObject.name + " was selected");

        //Invoke Event
        if (OnSelectedEvent != null)
        {
            OnSelectedEvent(this.gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, you can subscribe and un-subscribe to the event in the `OnEnable` and `OnDisable` functions respectively script from another script:

```
void OnEnable()
{
    //subscribe to event
    LanguageDropdown.OnSelectedEvent += SelectAction;
}

void OnDisable()
{
    //Un-subscribe to event
    LanguageDropdown.OnSelectedEvent -= SelectAction;
}

//This will be called when invoked
void SelectAction(GameObject target)
{
    Debug.Log(target.name + " was selected");
}
```

> Basically I wanted to know if I am forced to attach the script
>   LanguageDropdown to the gameobject, or If this is not required and I
>   can setup everything from another script which is not attached to that
>   specific dropdown.

No, you can use the `EventTrigger` class to register the events like below and you won't have to attach it to each object:

```
EventTrigger.Entry entry = new EventTrigger.Entry();
entry.eventID = EventTriggerType.Select;
entry.callback.AddListener((eventData) => { SelectAction(); });
```

Please, do **not** use that. It is slow and I have verified this from multiple people too.

Comment: I think I was not clear in my question. Basically I wanted to know if I am forced to attach the script `LanguageDropdown` to the dropdown gameobject, or If this is not required and I can setup everything from another script which is not attached to that specific dropdown, by just referencing to the dropdown gameobject from that script.

Answer (score 3):

A Unity-centric solution would be to use a `UnityEvent` which lets you make these changes in the inspector.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class LanguageDropdown : MonoBehaviour, ISelectHandler// required interface when using the OnSelect method.
{
    public UnityEvent Selected;

    //Do this when the selectable UI object is selected.
    public void OnSelect(BaseEventData eventData)
    {
        Debug.Log(this.gameObject.name + " was selected");
        Selected.Invoke();
    }
}
```

Then the `LanguageDropdown` component will have a *Selected* member visible in the inspector to which you can then assign an Object and method target (much like a Button).

[image: Component with *Selected()* member visible]

Note: You can change `UnityEvent` to `UnityEvent<LanguageDropdown>` if you want to include the source object:

```
public class LanguageDropdown : MonoBehaviour, ISelectHandler// required interface when using the OnSelect method.
{
    public UnityEvent<LanguageDropdown> Selected;

    //Do this when the selectable UI object is selected.
    public void OnSelect(BaseEventData eventData)
    {
        Debug.Log(this.gameObject.name + " was selected");
        Selected.Invoke(this);
    }
}
```

The target method must then have the correct parameter list

(i.e. `public void method(LanguageDropdown dropdown)` )

Answer (score 1):

You can define public method in another script, and call it int `OnSelect()` implementation.

For example:

```
public interface IDropdownContext
{
    void OnDropdownSelected(BaseEventData eventData);
}

public class Test : MonoBehaviour, IDropdownContext
{

    public void OnDropdownSelected(BaseEventData eventData)
    {
        Debug.Log("OnDropdownSelected");
    }
}


public class LanguageDropdown : MonoBehaviour, ISelectHandler// required interface when using the OnSelect method.
{
    [SerializeField]
    public Test context;

    //Do this when the selectable UI object is selected.
    public void OnSelect(BaseEventData eventData)
    {
        Debug.Log(this.gameObject.name + " was selected");

        context.OnDropdownSelected(eventData);
    }
}
```