# Transform position not updated immediately

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I made an animation event once animation completes, it updates transform position, then call a method to check if player land on a specific tile.

However, the transform position was not updated immediately. I wrote a coroutine to wait for a short time.

A simple case:

```
public void OnAnimationFinish() {
    transform.position = landOn;
    Debug.Log("Start from: " + landOn);

    JumpIfOnTile();
}

private void JumpIfOnTile() {
    // not same if you don't wait
    Debug.Log("Start from: " + transform.position);
}
```

Workaround:

```
private IEnumerator JumpIfOnTile() {
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(.5f);
    // then everything ok
    Debug.Log("Start from: " + transform.position);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure `JumpIfonTile` is not called from somewhere else? This seems impossible especially if the first `Log` inside `OnAnimationFinish` shows the updated `transform.position`. Could you put a breakpoint in `OnAnimationFinish` and test what exactly happens?

Comment: @MartinZikmund seems set position to `landOn` is not actually updating position.

Comment: Does the first `Log` ouptut the `landOn` position or not?

Comment: @MartinZikmund actually I printed `landOn`. I edited the post.

Comment: Is the animation also modifying the position? If the animation hasn't actually finished completely, it may not let you to update it

Comment: @MartinZikmund I hooked `OnAnimationFinish` on the last frame. Theoretically the animation should be done. It possibly be your case, but I don't understand the way animator works, there may be an event system taking care of param updating per frame (thus not immediately).

Comment: I am not sure as well, just guessing :-D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I hooked OnAnimationFinish on the last frame. Theoretically the
>   animation should be done.

It looks the animation is not really done and is overwriting the position you set to the object. Instead of waiting for `.5f` sec which is really long, wait for the end of frame when the animation is likely done and this is done with `yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame()`. If there is still a problem just wait for a frame with `yield return null`.

While this should solve your issue, I wouldn't recommend that you use the built-in animation event to detect end of animation, just do that by code. See the `PlayAndWaitForAnim` function from my other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40587340/3785314) which shows how to play animation then wait for it to finish playing. Move your transformation at the end of that `PlayAndWaitForAnim` function.

**EDIT:**

> why I have to wait for a frame?

Remember I said you can wait till the end of the frame with `WaitForEndOfFrame` or for a frame. Unity is updating the animation every frame. Since you had the event set to the last frame, you can't guarantee when the event is called (before or after the last frame). If the event is invoked before the frame and you set the position, the animation will overwrite it at the end of the frame. This is why you wait till the end of frame or just one frame to guarantee that the animation is no longer animating. Watch [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6fD8AclRaAI) video to get more insight on what's going on.

> why do you prefer scripting instead of builtin anim event? Is it
>   occasionally behaving unexpectedly?

I prefer scripting for this because it avoids issues just like the one in your question. There should be a warning on the animation event documentation that says *"Do not use this"*. The animation event can cause a slow bug is your game and this issue randomly occur. I am not sure if this has been fixed fixed. The worst thing it can do is not being called at-all and this happens when your animation mistakenly skips a frame due to low frame rate. They claim they have fixed this issue but it's [not true](https://forum.unity.com/threads/animation-events-not-always-firing-mecanim.428786/#post-3442813). The callback function not being called can completely break your game.

If you need callback type event for the animation, implement an [event and delegate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47040232/3785314) in the `PlayAndWaitForAnim` function I linked. Do not use Unity's animation event.

Comment: Thanks for replying. It may not directly relate to this issue but can you explain more about 1. why I have to wait for a frame? I assume an event system is polling on each frame, and handle async calls from anim, scripts, etc.; 2. why do you prefer scripting instead of builtin anim event? Is it occasionally behaving unexpectedly? I ask because I haven't seen "best practice" on official site. Nor did I have read a whole explanations about animation event.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set a condition before `JumpIfOnTile();` executed. e.g.

```
public void OnAnimationFinish() {
    transform.position = landOn;
    Debug.Log("Start from: " + transform.position);

    if(transform.position == landOn)
    JumpIfOnTile();
}
```

Comment: I edited the post. In your case the condition failed.